# Setting a image as backButton

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set a BackButton as a image instead of the standard text and backArrow, but whatever i do it wont work. i've tried hiding the BackButton and setting leftBarbutton, but then the backButton is not hidng and i've tried setting backBarButtonItem as below, but still only appearing the standard backButton. What am i doing wrong?

```
    var backButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "left"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("goBack:"))

    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton
```

tried now

```
    var backButton:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "left"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("goBack:"))

    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should'nt use `self.navigationController?.navigationItem` but `self.navigationItem` directly!

But anyway, for more background:

> When this navigation item is immediately below the top item in the stack, the navigation controller derives the back button for the navigation bar from this navigation item.

(From Apples documentation of `backBarButtonItem`
)

That means, the `backBarButton` item property can only change the back button appearance of the next viewController you push onto your `UINavigationController`'s stack.

To achieve the desired effect, you can

1. set a `leftBarButtonItem` (this should automatically hide the back button) and call `self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` manually when it's clicked

or

2. use the `UINavigationBar.appearance()` API.

Comment: How do i set the backButton invisible cause i've tried setting hideBackButton to true, but not working

Comment: updated the answer. setting leftBarButtonItem should automatically hide back button. also setting hidesBackButton could interfere with that - so try only setting leftBarButton item

Comment: i've added the current code which i've added to the viewController. The viewController is being presented show e.g push if that makes a difference

Comment: I think you should'nt use `self.navigationController?.navigationItem` but `self.navigationItem` directly!

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a UIButton and set its Image, frame and add target.

   ```
   UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage"];
   [backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
   backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40);
   [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   ```
2. Using this backButton define a UIBarButtonItem and assign that to
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem

   ```
   UIBarButtonItem* barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
   ```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's using swift not objc